# What is the logic that pgfplot set the picture's width?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, scaling

If the code is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \begin{axis}[
      axis lines=middle,%axis equal,
      ymin=-4,ymax=9,
      xmin=-1.5, xmax=57,
      xtick={0,1,...,7},
      ytick={1,...,8},
      xlabel={$x$},
      xlabel style={anchor=west},
      ylabel={$y$},
      ylabel style={anchor=east},
      grid=both,grid style={line width=0.6pt, draw=gray!10},
      samples=2 
    ]
    \addplot[blue!50,domain=-16:6,name path=plot1,dashed] {-(5/6)*x+(29/6)}
      node[near start,sloped]{$5x+6y=29$};
    \addplot[blue!50,domain=-2.5:6,name path=plot2,dashed]{-(9/4)*x+(35/4)}
      node[fdesc]{$9x+4y=35$};
      \addplot[red,domain=-1:6,name path=plot3,<->,thick]{-(5/4)*x+6}
      node[fdesc]{target};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Then it looks like
[image]

I wonder why didn't the `pgfplots` generate a huge width picture? Even if I set the `xmax` to a proper value, say `7`, then it now becomes

[image]

It appears to me that the actual width of the picture is constant.  But I can't tell from what part in my code that I require the system to do this. So, how to understand the logic of that how wide does `pgfplots` set for a picture?

Comment: The width of the picture is set by the options of `{tikzpicture}`. Generally that width is generated by the content; That is, if you specify (tikz) coordinates such as `(0,0) -- (2,2)`, the resulting image will be 2x2 centimetres in size. With `[width=, height=, size]` you can set the scaling. Pgfplots deals with coordinates that frequently do not relate to centimetres or points or anything. Here a "reasonable" picture size is chosen.

Comment: @Huang_d Not really the `tikzpicture`, rather the `axis`, `width` and `height` aren't valid keys for TikZ. Eric: Part of the point of `pgfplots` is to scale data so that a plot will have a reasonable size whether the plot goes from 0 to 0.1, or from 0 to 10000. There is a default size for the `axis`, see section 4.10.1 in the manual.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I see, thanks for the clarification. I misremembered that, width and height are indeed set within the picture, not by passing options to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The part of your code that makes this happen is `\begin{axis}` and `\end{axis}`, which requires `\usepackage{pgfplots}`.

TikZ has long been able to plot functions, using e.g.

```
\draw plot (\x,2*\x);
```

The problem with this is that in most cases you would have to scale the plot in order to get a reasonable size of the diagram, and if you want axes with ticks and ticklabels those have to be constructed manually. And I don't think there is any way of easily reading in data from text files with this method either.<sup>1</sup>

But TikZ is a general purpose library for making diagrams. `pgfplots` on the other hand, is designed specifically for plotting data or functions, and a part of doing that is to scale the data so that the axis gets a reasonable size, regardless of the range of the data. This is the as you'd expect if you were plotting data in some other program, like `matplotlib`, `bokeh`, Matlab, Excel etc.

The default size of an axis, given in section 4.10.1 of the `pgfplots` manual, is

- a width of 240pt, and
- a height of 207pt.

(1pt = 1/72.27in, so this is about 8.4cm and  7.3cm). You can change the size with the `width` and `height` keys, which can be added to the options of the `axis`, e.g.

```
\begin{axis}[
  width=5cm,
  height=3cm,
  ...
```

One other thing to note is that the width and height by default should include the axis labels and ticklabels, so the axis frame itself is smaller. You can override that with `scale only axis`, so with

```
\begin{axis}[
  width=5cm,
  height=3cm,
  scale only axis,
  ...
```

the total width will be 5cm plus whatever width the label/ticklabels on the y-axis add.

---

<sup>1</sup> Version 3 of TikZ introduced a new library, `datavisualization` which has the same purpose as `pgfplots`, making plots of data or functions. It is still more limited than `pgfplots` I think, and the approach is a bit different.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, is it common to manually calculate what the width of the picture should be with respect to the ranges of x or y axis everytime? Is there another quick way?

Comment: I somehow feel I don't get used to the way `pgfplots` specify the size of the picture. I remember that TikZ would automatically generate a picture with respect to the coordinates that has path or graphs on it. And the x axis unit length : y axis unit length = 1:1. Well, maybe it is because when dealing with functional graphs, the way that `pgfplots` specifies the size of the picture is more flexible and smart? I don't have idea. Maybe I should ask how to sets the ratio of two axis' unit length to be 1 in `pgfplots`.

Comment: @Eric For the first comment: Eh, I don't know if it's common, don't think so. For the second: For a plot like the one you showed it might make sense to not do any scaling, but try plotting for example `exp(x)` for the domain `0:20`. Or `0.001*sin(x)` for the domain `0:2000`. With `pgfplots` both of those cases will give you a reasonable plot without any modifications, with pure TikZ, not so much. For the last part, add `axis equal` to the options of the `axis` environment.

Comment: @Eric (If I answer badly, I guess that is partly because that I don't really understand your confusion. Making sure a plot has a certain size regardless of the range of the axes is to me the only natural thing to do for something like `pgfplots`.)